# How to list all VM instances in all my projects and also list their assigned vCPU and memory as well?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

Totally new to gcloud here... I'm trying to list all VM instances along with assigned amount of vCPU and memory to each instances. I've successully listed the instances using instances.list method, but could not find assigned vCPU and memory info within the response body for instances.list method.
I followed the code on [gcloud command to display vCPU's and Memory assigned to Instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65888736/gcloud-command-to-display-vcpus-and-memory-assigned-to-instances) to try and get that info, but got an error.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.list) The project property is set to the empty string, which is invalid.
```

Is there a way for me to address this error? I'm also open to other methods to retrieve the same data.

Answer (score 0):

The config setting for the project is not set. Run this command:

```
gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
```

Make sure you use the Project ID and not the Project Name.

[gcloud config set](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set)